# Opening a newly created site collection with SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, site-collection, sharepoint-server

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I can't seem to open my newly created site collection in SPD 2010. I created the site in Central Administration but when I open SPD and click "Open Site", it shows me a list of previously created site collections but not the new one.

How do I get the site collection to show up here?

Comment: Ok I found out that you can enter the URL for your site into the Textbox "Site name". A different label would have been really helpful here as I spend the last hour with this.

Answer (score 1):

you have to click on "Open Site".

There a new window appears...you can type your site url and **CLICK OPEN** (don't press ENTER)
here's an exemple:

[image]